# after update updated to 16.04 Unable to open desktop

Tags: 16.04, kde

We had initially installed KDE under Ubuntu 14.x. We've now upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04. After the upgrade, the desktop no longer opens.

We tried the command:

```
sudo apt install Ubuntu-desktop
```

But it is showing the following error..

```
unable to show package in Ubuntu desktop
```

I would very much appreciate some help here.

---

Thanks in advance,
Vinit Kher

Comment: what exactly do you mean by opening the desktop?

Comment: maybe you want to use  ```sudo apt-get install Ubuntu-desktop ``` instead of ```sudo apt install Ubuntu-desktop ```?

Comment: @wair92, with 16.04 `apt` is recommended over `apt-get`.

Comment: 16.04 uses apt. You need the lower case "u" in `ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: @anonymous2 Thank you for the info, I didnt notice it.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a capitalisation error.  The command you're looking for is:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```